# Function not working when put after calling it

Tags: python, function

Does anyone know why when I put my function after calling it, it doesn't work but if I put it before it is does?

```
question = input("type any key to start")
if type(question == str):
    game()

def game():
    print("Rock paper or scissors")
```

This doesn't work put when I put def game() above in the beginning, it does.

Comment: Calling before defining would raise a `NameError` since at the time of _calling_, there's nothing _to call_.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your code this way:

```
def game():
    print("Rock paper or scissors")
question = input("type any key to start")
if type(question == str):
    game()
```

You can only call a function after it's definition